# What are the AIM values for aliens and EXALT agents?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I can see all of my units AIM values, both before the mission and during the mission with any modifiers for height advantage etc.

What are the corresponding values for the aliens? Is it different for different types of aliens - are Floaters better shots than Thin Men? What about the EXALT agents? Logically it would seem that their snipers would get the same bonuses as XCOM units.

I believe the values may be different between difficulty levels also.

Comment: One way to see and test this could be Mind Controling aliens and check results from there.

Comment: I suspect the answers are in XML files somewhere, but don't have time to check.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the stats from all units on [X-COM Wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/). If you go on the article for whatever unit, there is a box in the upper right corner, which contains a picture and all the stats you want. The different rows mean the different difficulties:

Easy | Normal | Classic | Imposssible

For example the [Thin Man](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Thin_Man):

On Classic difficultiy, he has 75 Aim, 10 Crit Chance and 4 HP.

All other modifiers (like height advantage) count the same for aliens, as they count for the player. However, you need to keep in mind that some enemy units (for example the EXALT Elite Sniper) also have some perks like `Depth Perception`, which will also tweak their base stats in certain situations. These bonus stats are not part of the base stats you can check in the information box about that unit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, different races of aliens have different Aim values. And yes, the Aim values, as well as all other stats, also vary by difficulty.

You can look up the exact stats of all enemies in the file DefaultGameCore.ini. When you installed the game via steam into the default directory, you can find that file in

`Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\XCom-Enemy-Unknown\XComGame\Config\`

It's not as beautiful as looking it up on a wiki, but it's much more reliable because they are the values the game is actually using and do not come from a secondary source which might have made a typo when copying the values or might be outdated.

Here is [a detailed explanation of the DefaultGameCore.ini](http://wiki.tesnexus.com/index.php/DefaultGameCore.ini_settings_-_XCOM:EU_2012)